# Ajax code not working even if it is (i think) correct

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

The function that this do is when the user clicked the button, it will execute the Ajax codes and then get the value of the input and send it to the PHP file and then send it back to the Ajax code to display the message from the MySQL table.

I tried changing my codes, changing div ids, changing syntax, clearing block of codes but none seems to work.

> AJAX

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#snd").click(function() {
        var msgg = $('input[name=message]').val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'automatedchat_func.php',
            data: {newmsg: msgg},
            success: function(data) {
                $("#conversation").html(data);
            }
        });
    });
 });
</script>
```

> HTML **UPDATED**

```
<div class="convo">
                <div class="convo_field" id="conversation">



                </div>
                <div class="obj">
                    <div class="txtbox">
                    <form method="POST">
                        <input type="input" id="msg" name="message" placeholder="Type exact or related word(s) of your question"/>
                   </form>
                    </div>
                    <div class="but_send"><button id="snd" name="send">SEND</button></div>
                </div>
                </div>
```

> PHP **UPDATED**

```
<?php
include 'database/connect.php';

session_start();


 $sql = "SELECT * FROM ai WHERE keywords LIKE '%$_POST[message]%' OR '$_POST[message]%_' OR '$_POST[message]_'";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    if ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "Hi ". $_SESSION['name'] .".<br> " . $row['message'];
    }

?>
```

Comment: What error are you getting ? have you checked console from browser ? and check what error it gives

Comment: Well your JS and HTML looks like it would work, have you confirmed that the PHP script is actually returning anything? Does the MySQL fail - is a row actually returned..?

Comment: Plus (and i hope you are already aware) that your SQL is wide open to abuse there (expect a few links to [bobby tables](https://xkcd.com/327/))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Changes with suggestion(in comment):-***

```
<div class="convo">
    <div class="convo_field" id="conversation">
    </div>
    <div class="obj">
        <div class="txtbox">
            <input type="input" id="msg" name="message" placeholder="Type exact or related word(s) of your question"/>
        </div><!-- form not requird -->
        <div class="but_send"><button id="snd" name="send">SEND</button></div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Add jquery library so that jquery code wiil work -->

<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#snd").click(function() {
        var msgg = $('#msg').val();  // id is given so use that, its more easy
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'automatedchat_func.php',
            data: {newmsg: msgg},
            success: function(data) {
                $("#conversation").html(data);
            }
        });
    });
 });
</script>
```

***automatedchat_func.php(must be in the same working directory where your above html file exist)***

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);// check all type of error
ini_set('display_errors',1);// display all errors
include 'database/connect.php';
session_start();
$final_result='';//a variable
if(isset($_POST['newmsg']) && !empty($_POST['newmsg'])){// its newmsg  not message
    $message = $_POST['newmsg'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM ai WHERE keywords LIKE '%$message%' OR '$message%' OR '$message'"; // check the change ere
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { // while needed
        $final_result .="Hi ". $_SESSION['name'] .".<br> " . $row['message']."<br>";
    }
}else{
    $final_result .="Hi please fill the input box first";
}
echo $final_result; // send final result as response to ajax
?>
```

Note:- your query is still vulnerable to SQL Injection. So read for `prepared statements` and use them

Comment: Thanks MAN! it works!

Yup i know my query is not safe, i'll work on it when I finish this thesis website I am working :)